# How do I "dedup" rows based on most recently updated

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Lets say I have a table whose content looks like

```
ID     Name      Last Update
============================
1      A         1 JAN 2018
1      A         2 JAN 2018
1      A         3 JAN 2018
2      B         3 JAN 2018
2      B         6 JAN 2018
```

I want to get the result

```
ID     Name      Last Update
============================
1      A         3 JAN 2018
2      B         6 JAN 2018
```

How can I do it?

I tried to group by ID but, how do I get the most recent?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @Nik's solution can work in situations where there are either no ties for the `MAX(date)` values (or it doesn't matter which tie value gets selected and whether this produces multiple output rows), an alternative approach is to group all records by `ID` sort all records belonging to one group by `date` in descending order and then pick the very first result row per group.

This can be achieved by using the SQL standard window function `ROW_NUMBER()` like this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, DATE
FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID 
                               ORDER BY DATE DESC) RN
            , ID
            , NAME
            , DATE
      FROM <TABLE_NAME>
      ) 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this to get the results that you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  (ID, date) IN (SELECT 
                            ID, MAX(Last Update) 
                      FROM table
                      GROUP BY ID)
```

Comment: This solution is correct under the condition that the `date` values have unique MAX-values. For records with ties, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @LarsBr. . . . I think it is very reasonable to assume that the dates are unique.  In fact, an update date would typically have a full time component as well.  More troublesome is that not all databases support tuples with `in` and the subquery is not syntactically correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, I fixed the example's syntax issue. I still think it's important to be aware of the constraint concerning the unique MAX value. That's something easy to overlook as no compiler warning will happen. If the database doesn't support tupel comparison, then this becomes very obvious very soon.